# SQL Server count number of records having the same value then group by

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

I have a table called **ReportStats**
  the table columns are:
  **Id**, **MemberId**, **Action** and **RecordId**.
  the action can have a value of *create, change or deactivate*
  what I want to do is count the number of each action per **MemberId**
  is this posible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE #ReportStats (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), MemberId INT, [Action] VARCHAR(10))
```

**Insert some sample data**

```
INSERT INTO #ReportStats VALUES (1, 'create'),
                                (1, 'create'),
                                (1, 'change'),
                                (1, 'deactivate'),
                                (1, 'change'),
                                (1, 'deactivate'),
                                (2, 'create'),
                                (2, 'change'),
                                (2, 'change'),
                                (2, 'change'),
                                (2, 'change'),
                                (2, 'deactivate')
```

A simple `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` will do the trick:

**Query**

```
SELECT
    MemberId,
    Action,
    COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM #ReportStats
GROUP BY MemberId, Action
ORDER BY MemberId
```

**Output**

```
MemberId    Action      Cnt
1           change      2
1           create      2
1           deactivate  2
2           change      4
2           create      1
2           deactivate  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Other way of doing the same is by using count funtion along with OVER clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MemberId,
    Action,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID,Action) as CntAction
FROM #ReportStats
```